# Which is the technically correct term: Nose Gear or Nose Landing Gear?

Tags: terminology, landing-gear

Talking about landing gear system, came across my mind the correct and technical name. Is it NOSE GEAR or NOSE LANDING GEAR?

Comment: I find the term "_Landing_ gear" rather misleading, is it retracted for taxi and take-off?

Comment: The terms are interchangeable.  I've seen Boeing maintenance manuals refer to it as a 'Nose Gear'.  But both terms are fine; people will understand it either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the ATA iSpec 2200, ATA Standard Numbering System, which provides a standard for structuring maintenance data by the manufacturers. The structure helps the airlines by providing a common structure regardless of manufacturer.  While voluntary, most aircraft manufacturers use it.

The spec is organized into chapters by aircraft system. ATA Chapter 32 is **LANDING GEAR**. Chapter subsections cover subsystems.  Subsection -10 is **Main Gear and Doors** and subsection -20 is **Nose Gear and Doors**.  So that's the 'common' terminology in the aircraft manufacturing and maintenance world.

Answer (score 2):

From [FAA order 5300.7](http://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/construction_5300_7.pdf), Nose Gear seems to be the correct word.
[image]